Cannot write data to BigQuery when using Databricks secret
I am following this guide on writing data to the BigQuery table.
Right now, I have an error when I try to write data using Databricks Secret instead of the JSON credential file and setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://169.x.x.x/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

What is strange here is I can write/read the data using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. I can also read the data using Databricks Secret. So I don't know why it is not work when I write the data with Databricks Secret.
Here is my code to read the Databricks Secret:
import base64

cred = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="bigquery-scope", key="secret-name").encode('ascii')
cred = base64.b64encode(cred)
cred = cred.decode('ascii')
spark.conf.set("credentials", cred)

Below is my code to read/write the data:
# Read data
df = spark.read.format("bigquery")
    .option("parentProject", <parent-project-id>)
    .option("viewsEnabled","true")
    .option("table", <table-name>)
    .load()

# Write data
df.write.format("bigquery") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket", <bucket-name>) \
  .option("table", <table-name>) \
  .option("parentProject", <parent-project-id>) \
  .save()

Am I missing any configuration for writing the data to BigQuery with Databricks Secret?
Update:
I tried to read the Secret, write it into a temporary JSON file and set the path to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with this code but it still failed:
import os

# Retrieve the JSON credentials from Databricks Secrets
cred = dbutils.secrets.get("bigquery-cred", "project-id-name")

# Write the JSON to a temporary file
temp_cred_path = "/tmp/cred.json"
with open(temp_cred_path, "w") as temp_cred_file:
    temp_cred_file.write(cred)

# Set the environment variable to point to the JSON file
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = temp_cred_path

This is the full stacktrace:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-846265064717828> in <module>
      1 # this exports to Big Query -- note "overwrite" in method def above
----> 2 write_to_bigquery(table_name, bucket, dataset, project_id)

<command-846265064717827> in write_to_bigquery(tableName, tempBucket, df, project_id)
      1 def write_to_bigquery(tableName, tempBucket, df, project_id):
----> 2   df.write.format("bigquery") \
      3   .option("temporaryGcsBucket", tempBucket) \
      4   .option("parentProject", project_id) \
      5   .option("table", tableName) \

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    736             self.format(format)
    737         if path is None:
--> 738             self._jwrite.save()
    739         else:
    740             self._jwrite.save(path)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o679.save.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create default Credentials
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:46)
  while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier
    for the 3rd parameter of com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:63)
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:63)
  while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient

1 error
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1097)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1131)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:979)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create default Credentials
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.createDefaultCredentials(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:101)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.<init>(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule$$FastClassByGuice$$b1b60333.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1094)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:124)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.createDefaultCredentials(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:99)
    ... 64 more

I think this error message is the main reason my code cannot run:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.


have you tried printing it after retrieving from dbutils ? Does it retrieve correct format ?

@GeorginaSkibinski yes, I tried print the credential in both read and write job. They are the same. I use the same code to read the Databricks secret in both jobs too.

can you post 1. All "Caused by" from your full stacktrace? 2. Try to invoke that API yourself using curl/python? 3. Post full spark.conf. 4. Create a new SparkSession with existing session's spark.conf + credential config and then use new_spark_session.read... (I doubt it's the issue, but I've seen that changing spark conf after creation, doesn't always work). 5. Lastly can't you set env variable from your python code instead of setting credential in config?

Set root logger to TRACE level and see if you can find more info on how Spark/Google is trying to authenticate.

@Kashyap I tried to write the secret into a temporary json file and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable but it failed. I posted the full stacktrace of it. For the first code, the "Caused by" is just 404 Not Found.

Can't really help if you don't post any answers. Anyway...
